# How can I initialize and use 64-bit integer in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, int

The [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/mini-max-sum) requires me to use 64-bit integer.
How can I initialize and implement that in python3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You've misinterpreted their warning. They're telling you to use a larger type than normal in order to avoid overflow issues seen with a 32-bit type. Since Python's `int` is essentially boundless there will never be an overflow issue.

Answer (score 10):

Frankly, sometimes it is bad to use unlimited integers in Python. Best alternative is to use NumPy fixed length types if you really need exactly 32bit or 64bit ops.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.uint64(99)
q = np.uint64(12) * v + np.uint64(77)

print(q)
print(type(q))
```